# Как можно делать временные задержки во втором потоке?

Tags: c++, qt

Вопрос для меня насущный.
Приходится создавать программы для управления внешними датчиками и реле. Как все мы знает управлять нужно циклически с заданными интервалами времени. Если все это управление запихивать в главный поток и по таймеру вызывать то начинает тормозить GUI. Приходится создавать второй поток и в нем управлять. Но как правильно во втором потоке задавать временные интервалы ?

```
while(true)
{
//управление
//задержка
//..
}
```

Comment: А что мешает во втором потоке сделать таймер и по нему выполнять управление?

Comment: ни чего не мешает но может есть еще какие решения, более элегантные.

Comment: а что у тебя там такого, что гуйня начинает тормозить, если вызывать из главного потока?

Comment: Вопрос вкуса ,конечно, но как по мне - элегантнее таймеров ничего не придумаешь для управления интервалами времени.

Comment: Просто промышленные пк слабые. У них повышенная помехозащищенность а мощности не какой.

Comment: Если душа просит чего-то более элегантного, то можно машину состояний прикрутить (Qt'шную или свою набросать на коленке), но к тому, в отдельном ли она будет потоке или нет отношения это не имеет, а под капотом там всё равно таймеры будут...

Comment: 'Машина состояний' не учитывает временные интервалы. С помощью ее можно описать переходы по простому граф.

Comment: @zhilenkov, «ожидание окончания таймера» — это тоже состояние... можешь посмотреть пример «светофор» из стандартного комплекта... но если у тебя логика слишком простая, то это, конечно, будет из «пушки по воробьям»...

Comment: «ожидание окончания таймера» — это тоже состояние. Да не подумал об этом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы второй поток создаете не средствами Qt(или делаете это неверно).
Верный способ подразумевает перемещение объекта в другой поток управления `moveToThread()`.

```
QThread* thrd = new QThread();
myObject -> moveToThread(thrd);
thrd->start();
```

После чего, уже в этом объекте можно без проблем насоздавать таймеров.